# Should I mix Vue.js with a regular HTML, JS and CSS webpage?

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js, webpack

I'm a Vue.js noobie but already develop webpages using Webpack, ESLint, CSS preprocessors etc. My question is: can I just plug some Vue.js components in my webpage or should I build the entire webpage with Vue? Is Vue meant to augment a webpage (where needed) or to wrap around one completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first para of [What is Vue?](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/)

> Vue (pronounced /vjuː/, like view) is a progressive framework for building user interfaces. Unlike other monolithic frameworks, Vue is designed from the ground up to be incrementally adoptable. The core library is focused on the view layer only, and is easy to pick up and integrate with other libraries or existing projects. On the other hand, Vue is also perfectly capable of powering sophisticated Single-Page Applications when used in combination with modern tooling and supporting libraries.

There is also a [Comparison with Other Frameworks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html) that covers React, HTML & CSS, Angular, Ember, Knockout...

In general stackoverflow is more focussed on solving specific coding issues than answering questions seeking how-to or opinion-based / subjective questions, so you might be better off looking at the Vue pages I linked, or searching the broader web.